# Pamtester automate password testing

Tags: root, authentication, pam

We have a system image which uses a default password for root. This *should* be changed, though I have a feeling not all users do this.

I know I can test login with pamtester:

```
# pamtester system-auth root authenticate
Password:
```

It asks for the password on the command line. I want to automate this. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using the [Expect](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

```
vi ./authenticate_test.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Checking your password. If it doesn't work, script will wait for a few seconds, don't worry..."

pamtester login $1 authenticate << eof
`echo $2`
eof

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "script> Successful"
else
  echo "script> Fail"
fi
```

Then use:

```
$ ./authenticate_test.sh customuser rightpassword
Checking your password. If it doesn't work, script will wait for a few seconds, don't worry...
Password: pamtester: successfully authenticated
script> Successful
```

```
$ ./authenticate_test.sh customuser wrongpassword
Checking your password. If it doesn't work, script will wait for a few seconds, don't worry...
Password: pamtester: Authentication failure
script> Fail
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the hash in the /etc/shadow file.  You already have the hash, since it's part of your image.  Just make sure the root password hash is different.

Answer (score -1):

A `here-document` does the trick as well:

```
testparm ... << eof
`echo $password`
eof
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me, how does it work. I suggest to elaborate your answer.